# HTML CSS Content div won't float over

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am trying to place the content div over both background divs but instead my code sets it only on the bottom div. Below there are 2 images that show you what I want to achieve and what is happening.

Image 1: What I want to achieve
[image: Goal]

Image 2: The problem
[image: The problem]

HTML:

```
<div class="middle">
<div class="middle_bot">


    <div id="content">
        <p class="big">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Curabitur tellus felis, sagittis at neque placerat, 
        laoreet mollis massa. Sed et purus mollis, fringilla 
        tellus et, tincidunt eros. Ut dolor ipsum, feugiat et 

        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.middle
{

background-image: url(images/bg_middle.png); /* fallback */
background-image: url(images/bg_middle.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#000000), to(#009dca)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
background-image: url(images/bg_middle.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #009dca); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
background-image: url(images/bg_middle.png),    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #ffffff); /* FF3.6+ */
background-image: url(images/bg_middle.png),     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #009dca); /* IE10 */
background-image: url(images/bg_middle.png),      -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #009dca); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image: url(images/bg_middle.png),         linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000, #009dca); /* W3C */

    /*background-color:blue;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background: url(images/bg_middle.png);*/
    height: 40%;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle_bot
{

background-image: url(images/bg_middle2.png); /* fallback */
background-image: url(images/bg_middle2.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#000000), to(#ffffff)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
background-image: url(images/bg_middle2.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #ffffff); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
background-image: url(images/bg_middle2.png),    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #ffffff); /* FF3.6+ */
background-image: url(images/bg_middle2.png),     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #ffffff); /* IE10 */
background-image: url(images/bg_middle2.png),      -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #ffffff); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image: url(images/bg_middle2.png),         linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000, #ffffff); /* W3C */

    /*background-color:blue;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background: url(images/bg_middle2.png);*/
    height: 50%;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

#content
{
    background: url(images/content2.png);
    width: 800px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #373737;
    margin: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
}
```

Comment: Is there any relationship between the content of `middle`, `middle-bot` and `content` or are `middle` and `middle-bot` just for decoration?

Comment: Just for decoration. They should only act as backgrounds i.e. top half=middle and bottom half=middle_bot.

Comment: I don't see any z-indexes in your code. That would allow you to stack them like you have in your pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that simplifies your code and replicates the layout you're describing:

CSS:

```
 #Navigation{
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    background:black;}

#Middle{
    height:200px;
    overflow:visible;
    background:brown;}

#Content{
    margin:0px auto;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    background:blue;}

#MiddleBottom{
    height:200px;
    background:green;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Navigation">navigation<div>

<div id="Middle">
    <div id="Content"></div>    
</div>

<div id="MiddleBottom"></div>
```

And the jsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yLckv10v/) From here, you can adjust it to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I managed to figure out what my mistake was. By placing the "middlebottom" div outside of the "middle" div, I achieved the effect that I was looking for. Also your code clarified and simplified a few things in mine.